# Where to get PSPICE models of ceramic resonators?

Tags: rf, filter, spice, ltspice

I wish to design and simulate IF filters using ceramic resonators and crystal oscillators in OrCAD Capture or LT SPICE. The default libraries don't have any ceramics, so anyone know where to download libraries?

Comment: Some vendors give them on their websites.

Comment: They are the same as crystals. Values will be very different, of course.

Comment: @LeonHeller Do you know which parameters to change? The xtal library in OrCAD has frequency as the only configurable parameter.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Can you name some websites? I can't find any models on the Murata or Oscilent sites.

Comment: Virtually all the parameters will have to be changed. It's the same for different crystals.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent circuit of a ceramic resonator has the same form as quartz crystal resonator.  There is a capacitor representing the static capacitance of the device in parallel with a series RLC that represents the resonating characteristic of the device. In the Murata Ceramic Resonator Applications Manual, available at Murata.com, these circuits are described and values of the parameters are given for Murata resonators. You can easily input this circuit into LT Spice.